# Picklist value change throwing error

Tags: picklist, error, status

In a pick list, there are three status fields
 1. Open
 2. In-Progress
 3. Closed

Only Owner is able to change the status from *In-progress* to *Closed*. 
When other user changes it should throw an error.Others can only change the status from *Open* to *In-progress*.

How to obtain this using simple formula.Please help

Comment: Please provide the error details or Screen shot of error to get others a better view on it. Also please share any Validation rule details on object as well

Comment: This was asked in one of my interviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a validation rule to check values

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),'InProgress'),
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Closed'),
  $User.id != OwnerId
)
```

Basically is says

If the previous value was InProgress and is changing to Closed then if the Current User is not the owner evaluate to true and throw validation error

From your question

> Only Owner can change the status from In progress to Closed

it sounds like it was OK to change from open to closed...

If only owner can change to closed

> Others can only change the status from Open to In progress

then use this

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Closed'),
  $User.id != OwnerId
)
```